# How to nest Symfony form classes?

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine, entity

I am having issues figuring out the logic of how to create nested forms for the three entities I have: <kbd>Films</kbd>, <kbd>Actors</kbd> and <kbd>Locations</kbd>. I generated my Symfony entities (+`orm.xml`) from my database following the instructions in the symfony docs [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html).

My ultimate goal would to be have one page where the user can perform any of the following actions:

- Create a new <kbd>Films</kbd> object
- Select <kbd>Films</kbd> from a dropdown menu, and then create a new <kbd>Actors</kbd> object to associate to it
- Select <kbd>Films</kbd> from a dropdown menu, and then create a new <kbd>Locations</kbd> object to associate to it

(<kbd>Actors</kbd> and <kbd>Locations</kbd> both have a 1-to-many join with the `Films` table)

**However**, I've been struggling with the concept of nested forms in Symfony for a long time and in order to "walk before I can run" I'm just trying to put each of the above into separate routes with separate forms:

- `/newfilm`
- `/newactor`
- `/newlocation`

`/New-film` I can get working without problem. However, with either of the other two, anything I try doesn't seem to work. The below is my code, if someone can explain the "theory" of nested forms in Symfony to avoid keep hitting this wall would be very much appreciated...!

As my problem is the same for both Actor and Location, I'm only putting the code for for <kbd>Actors</kbd> (and <kbd>Films</kbd>) as I realise it's quite a lot already:

## ~~~~~Controller~~~~~

It is this second route (`/newactor`) which has the embedded/nested formType:

```
class DefaultController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/newfilm", name="new_film")
     */
    public function newFilmAction(Request $request)
    {
        $film = new Films();
        $form = $this->CreateFormBuilder($film)
            ->add('film_title','text',array('label'=>'Film title'))
            ->add('Save','submit',array('label'=>'Add new film'))
            ->getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($film);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('success_addFilm');
        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:newfilm.form.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }


    /**
     * @Route("/newactor", name="new_actor")
     */
    public function newActorAction(Request $request)
    {
        $actor = new Actors();
        $form = $this->createForm(new ActorType(), $actor);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($actor);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('success_addActor');
        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:newactor.form.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

## ~~~~~Films~~~~~

**Films.php**

```
/**
 * Films
 */
class Films
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $filmid;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $film_title;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Actors
     */
    private $actor;



    /**
     * Get filmid
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getFilmid()
    {
        return $this->filmid;
    }

    /**
     * Get film_title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFilm_title()
    {
        return $this->film_title;
    }

    /**
     * Set film_title
     * @param string $film_title
     * @return Films
     */
    public function setFilm_title($film_title)
    {
        $this->film_title = $film_title;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set actor
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Actors $actor
     *
     * @return Actors
     */
    public function setActor(\AppBundle\Entity\Actors $actor = null)
    {
        $this->actor = $actor;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get actor
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Actors
     */
    public function getActor()
    {
        return $this->actor;
    }
}
```

**Films.orm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="AppBundle\Entity\Films" table="Films">
    <indexes>
      <index name="fk_Films_actors1_idx" columns="actor_id"/>
    </indexes>
    <id name="filmid" type="integer" column="filmid">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
    <field name="film_title" type="text" column="film_title" length="65535" nullable="false">
      <options>
        <option name="fixed"/>
      </options>
    </field>
    <many-to-one field="actor" target-entity="Actors" fetch="LAZY">
      <join-columns>
        <join-column name="actor_id" referenced-column-name="actorid"/>
      </join-columns>
    </many-to-one>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

**FilmType.php**

```
class FilmType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('film_title');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'=>'AppBundle\Entity\Films'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'film';
    }
}
```

## ~~~~~Actors~~~~~

**Actors.php**

```
/**
 * Entries
 */
class Entries
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $actorid;


    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $actorName;




    /**
     * Set actorid
     *
     * @param integer $actorid
     *
     * @return Actors
     */
    public function setActorid($actorid)
    {
        $this->actorid = $actorid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get actorid
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getActorid()
    {
        return $this->actorid;
    }

    /**
     * Set actorName
     *
     * @param string $actorName
     *
     * @return Actors
     */
    public function setActorName($actorName)
    {
        $this->actorName = $actorName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get actorName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getActorName()
    {
        return $this->actorName;
    }
}
```

**Actors.orm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="AppBundle\Entity\Actors" table="Actors">
    <id name="actorid" type="integer" column="actorid">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
    <field name="actorName" type="text" column="actorName" length="65535" nullable="true">
      <options>
        <option name="fixed"/>
      </options>
    </field>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

**ActorType**

```
class ActorType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('actorName')
            ->add('film','entity',array(
              'class'=>'AppBundle:Films',
                'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('f')
                        ->orderBy('f.film_title','ASC');
                }
            ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'=>'\AppBundle\Entity\Actors'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'actor';
    }
}
```

My current error message is:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\Films could not be converted to string
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException

I have read answers that say to add in the function to my `Films.php`:

```
public function __toString() {
    return $this->name;
}
```

However, when I do that, I then get the error:

> Error: Method AppBundle\Entity\Films::__toString() must not throw an exception

Other possible ideas I've come across online (but unfortunately with no success) are:

- Setting the Forms as services
- Data transformers

Comment: why xml? yaml is much more readable

Comment: THanks for looking :) I've been trying to use 'best practices' and read this article which recommends using XML so that bundles are decoupled to use across projects....otherwise I agree I'd be getting less of a headache with annotations...! http://blog.danielribeiro.org/yes-you-can-have-low-coupling-in-a-symfony-standard-edition-application/

Comment: @Bendy that article is outdated. You should be using annotations if you want 'best practice'. http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html#doctrine-mapping-information

Comment: Thanks very much for the link - annotations are definitely clearer although for decoupling bundles it seems to make sense to have the database mappings in a separate file rather than interleaved with the entity php file...?

Comment: Use yaml in configuration files and use annotations in entities and controller classes as much as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `'choice_label'  =>  'film_title',` to your form builder. That or you can implement a `__toString()` function within your Film entity that returns the film title.

**Solution:**

```
$builder
    ->add('actorName')
    ->add('film','entity',array(
        'class'=>'AppBundle:Films',
        'choice_label'  =>  'film_title',
        'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('f')
                ->orderBy('f.film_title','ASC');
        }
    ));
```

Also, you may want to keep your entity names singular (eg: Film, not Films; Actor not Actors) as this may cause unnecessary issues when dealing with x-to-many entity relationships.

Comment: `choice_label` fixed it thank you! Your comment about keeping entity names singular - I had wondered about this too. However, database tables 'best practice' is to have the table named in plural for what is contained?

Comment: you can give your entity a singular name but your tables another name e.g. @ORM\Table(name="products") and your classname should be Product.